# Crystal Reports: Accessing printed records

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I've been working on a report that uses subreports to print records.
The problem is: for the same information, there may be several records - i.e.:

There may be several records for the same product if those records differ in one single column. My goal here is to make a **Record Selection** Formula that says: *"if that item is already shown, then don't show it once again."*

I've tried to use (shared) variables for this, but can't seem to find the way, because of the evaluation time.

Selection formulas are already being used to apply some filtering criteria. The column that may differ between two ocurrences of the same record is not always the same, so using a simple Selection Formula is not likely to work...

Any suggestions?

Example:

I used the record selection to tell the report:
"Show me all the products according to these criteria (warehouse=parameter1 and category=parameter2 for example)".

But there may be more than one record for the same product of the same category and inside the same warehouse, if one or more fields are different (for example, different price, different lot)

I want not to display those repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong... `Record Selection Forumula` is something that is applied at report level not on the `row level` or `column level`.

If you requirement is not to show the records that duplicates then you need to write the supress condition for those, As per your requirement apply supress condition to the rows or columns.

Comment: I used the record selection to tell the report:

Comment: Can you give an example or any screen shot how your data should look like?